# How to show javascript dialogs like NTLM dialog with webkitgtk

Tags: authentication, gtk, webkit, gtk3, webkitgtk

I am using webkitgtk container to display web page.However some pages require authentication and show javascript dialogs for authentication.How to handle it in webkitgtk?
I have tried setting the properties allow-modal-dialogs to true and javascript-can-open-windows-automatically to true

Answer (score 0):

NTLM dialogs are shown by default from webkitgtk2.30 version